# What is the difference between :after and ::after?

Tags: html, css

It says the difference is that :after is CSS2, while ::after is CSS3. Are there any more important differences?

(I've tried Googling, but the colons seem to throw off the search)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Pseudo-elements were denoted with a single colon in CSS2, but have been changed in CSS3 *"in order to establish a discrimination between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements"*. For compatibility reasons a single colon is still allowed for the pseudo-elements defined in CSS 1 and CSS2.

## [CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#before-and-after)

> ### 5.12.3 The :before and :after pseudo-elements
>
> The ':before' and ':after' pseudo-elements can be used to insert generated content before or after an element's content.

## [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements)

> ### 7. Pseudo-elements
>
> [...]
>
> A pseudo-element is made of two colons (`::`) followed by the name of the pseudo-element.
>
> This `::` notation is introduced by the current document in order to establish a discrimination between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements. **For compatibility with existing style sheets, user agents must also accept the previous one-colon notation for pseudo-elements introduced in CSS levels 1 and 2 (namely, :first-line, :first-letter, :before and :after). This compatibility is not allowed for the new pseudo-elements introduced in this specification.**

Comment: Can you check my edit there? Pretty sure that's what you meant but want to be sure I'm not missing something.

Answer (score 5):

`::after` won't work in some older browsers (I think IE8 is the only relevant one)

In general, you *should* use `::after` but there's no harm in using `:after` for compatibility, so long as you understand that it is a pseudo-*element*, not a pseudo-*class*

Answer (score 0):

On the contrary: ::after WORKS on IE8, while :after won't do it.

Comment: I think you might mean the other way around.  `::after` is the new syntax, and AFAIK IE8 doesn't support it.  OTOH no browser will ignore `:after`, for compatibility reasons.

Comment: I've tested in IE8 and :after won't work, while ::after works fine. I'll make the tests again to make sure anyway.

Comment: It might be odd to ask after 4 years but did you check it?